# Color Picker with one single Slider

Tags: java, android, c++, rgb, picker

Hi i'm implementing an android application, but this is offtopic.

I have a slider which can take valus between 0...16581375 (255*255*255), means all rgb values.

now technically this does work:

```
testText.setTextColor(0xff000000 + progress);
```

but when i'm sliding the color is flickering verry hard. How can i distribute the colors more harmonic

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the flicker has to do with you incrementing the combined rgb values with a base 10 value instead of a hex value. Here are some ideas of what to do in lieu of actually coding this myself.

1) Try converting your decimal values into hex before setting the text color

```
testText.setTextColor(Integer.valueOf(progress, 16));
```

Then just pass the value to the textcolor instead of adding it. Alpha defaults to ff (opaque) so you shouldn't have to worry about it here.

2) Make sure that the text color is changed in a handler or async task. The flickering may be caused by the application trying to process your commands synchronously.

3) The flickering may have to do with the alpha value (ff at the start of the hex) getting messed up somewhere along the lines in your code. Just follow it through your code to be sure.

4) Make sure that you aren't recreating the textview everytime the bar is moved. Define it in the asynctask or activity contructor.